# baseUrl in systemjs 0.20

Tags: systemjs

I just upgraded jspm 0.17-beta, systemjs 0.20.

I used to do `import { Class } from 'module'` and it would load `./dist/module.js`. Now it loads, `'./module'`.

I understand I can use packages in my `jspm.config.js` to set `"defaultExtension": "js"`, but how can I set the base url for non-mapped modules, in order to get the previous behavior.